# What method/property in a django field is called from the template?

Tags: django, django-models, django-templates

I want to subclass models.TextField so I can return the text to the template with occurences of `\r\n` replaced with `<br />`. I don't want the `<br />`'s stored in the database, however. What method is called to retrieve the field's data when invoked from the template?

I tried this, but it doesn't seem to work:

```
class HTMLTextField(models.TextField):
    def to_python(self, value):
        value = super(HTMLTextField, self).to_python(value)
        value = value.replace('\r\n', '<br />')
        value = value.replace('\n', '<br />')
        return mark_safe(value)
```

Thanks,
Pete

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An easier way of doing this is to use the [`linebreaks`](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.1/ref/templates/builtins/#linebreaks) filter in the template.

And just to clarify, even with the metaclass set, `to_python` isn't called from the template, but when the field is initially loaded from the database.

Answer (score 1):

I was missing this:

```
__metaclass__ = models.SubfieldBase
```

Well, I was missing this in my subclass, but I found a built-in template tag that does this `{{ textfield|linebreaksbr }}`, doh!